Make Object Not invisible until it passes a certain point
I have doors that close on a doorway not attached to any walls. Cannot hide the doors inside the walls.
Is there a way to only an object visible as it passes though a designated place. I want the door to be only visible inside the square.
Tried scaling the door, it looks awful. This is for an animation.


You have a few different options.
The first I thought of was an invisible “wall” mesh outside the door frame to Boolean the door halves away. If you hide it for renders, it should still work as a Boolean modifier target. This may not work if the door is not manifold (I.e. solidified, watertight).
The second would be to squash the door halves into the doorframe with shape keys or another deformation system, but you would have to make it squash one thinner-than-doorframe segment at a time somehow, or it wouldn’t look solid.
The third would be to use shading to make the door transparent where it was farther than a threshold away from the center of the door frame, on the axis parallel to where the wall would be. The threshold would be half the doorframe width. This would work on a flat plane non-manifold door, but only on that, and it would require extra configuration to ensure it still
worked even if the doorframe moved, and would need further configuration if the doorframe ever changed size. In other words, it would only work in one specific scenario and could not be completely reused for other doors in the scene.

There's also a YT tutorial on Scifi sliding doors here which might help.

@JohnEason I would call that a complete answer, but you’d have to pass it to text. It is superior to the options I suggested I think.

It's a video I saw some while ago so thought it worth mentioning but I wouldn't post a video link as an answer. I'm not currently well enough to write a full answer myself.
